# EFCore deleting referenced entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two entities in a project: `SupplierFinishingItem` and `ProductOptionListItem`.

`ProductOptionListItem` refrences the other by a navigation property.

When I try to create 1 `ProductOptionListItem` referencing a `SupplierFinishingItem` it works and saves the relation in the database.

But when I try to create 2 or more `ProductOptionListItem` referencing to the same `SupplierFinishingItem` only the first entity has the relation saved to the database. The others are saved with a `null` reference.

I managed to reproduce it in the smallest console application I could:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace relationship_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
            {
                var finishing = new SupplierFinishingItem { Name = "Finishing"};
                db.Finishings.Add(finishing);

                db.SaveChanges();

                db.Options.Add(new ProductOptionListItem { Name = "Option 1", SupplierFinishingItem = finishing });
                db.Options.Add(new ProductOptionListItem { Name = "Option 2", SupplierFinishingItem = finishing });
                db.Options.Add(new ProductOptionListItem { Name = "Option 3", SupplierFinishingItem = finishing });

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ProductOptionListItem> Options { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SupplierFinishingItem> Finishings { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=entity-test;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductOptionListItem>()
                .HasOne(p => p.SupplierFinishingItem)
                .WithMany(s => s.UsedBy)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.SupplierFinishingItemId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        }
    }

    public class ProductOptionListItem
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Guid? SupplierFinishingItemId { get; set; }
        public SupplierFinishingItem SupplierFinishingItem { get; set; }
    }

    public class SupplierFinishingItem
    {
        private HashSet<ProductOptionListItem> _usedBy;

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ProductOptionListItem> UsedBy => _usedBy?.ToList();
    }
}
```

The resulting database after I run this code is the following:

[image]

As you can see, only `Option 1` has a `SupplierFinishingItemId`, the other two are `NULL`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused by the implementation of the collection navigation property:

```
public IEnumerable<ProductOptionListItem> UsedBy => _usedBy?.ToList();
```

Returning new list instance from the getter somehow confuses the EF Core navigation property fixup code and produces the aforementioned effect (even before `SaveChanges() call).

The solution is to fix the implementation to not return new list on each call (which is considered a bad practice for property getter anyway), for instance:

```
public IEnumerable<ProductOptionListItem> UsedBy => _usedBy ?? (_usedBy = new HashSet<ProductOptionListItem>());
```

or configure EF Core to use the backing field directly:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductOptionListItem>()
    .HasOne(p => p.SupplierFinishingItem)
    .WithMany(s => s.UsedBy)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.SupplierFinishingItemId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
    .Metadata.PrincipalToDependent.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field); // <--
```

Comment: Can we just do `IEnumerable<ProductOptionListItem> UsedBy => _usedBy;` since `HashSet<>` implements `IEnumerable<>`?

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much! This was driving me crazy for days! I wish I could upvote it 100 times! :)

Comment: You are welcome :) @PaoloGo Yes, you can simply return the backing field from the getter, but that could lead to `null` exception in the calling code (except if you initialize the backing field), so I believe the suggested code is safer.